# How to conditionally import components inside modules in angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working on a angular app where I need to import the components on the basis of condition.I can achieve this by other methods which renders any one when it gets rendered on browser.But I need to get loaded any one of the component when I build this and before it gets inserted in DOM. Can anyone please help me with this? Here is my code.

Home.module.ts

```
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
    import { AboutUsComponentA } from './about-us-A.component';
    import { AboutUsComponentB } from './about-us-B.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    const isAboutusA = true
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        CollectionHomeComponent,
        BlogSectionComponenet,
        isAboutusA === true ? AboutUsAComponent:  AboutUsBComponent,// I need to achieve this, in this way this is not working. 
     
      ], 
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
    providers: []

   
    
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

AboutUsAComponent

```
import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
 @Component({
   template: ‘<div>This is the AboutUs A Component </div>’,
    styles: [‘:host {color: blue}’]
 })
export class AboutUsAComponent {}
```

AboutUsBComponent

```
import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
 @Component({
   template: ‘<div>This is the About Us B Component </div>’,
    styles: [‘:host {color: blue}’]
 })
export class AboutUsBComponent {}
```

HomeComponent

```
 import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
     @Component({
       template: ‘<div>This is the Home component
             <AboutUsAComponent></AboutUsAComponent>
             <AboutUsBComponent></AboutUsBComponent>
       </div>’,
        styles: [‘:host {color: blue}’]
     })
    export class HomeComponent {}
```

Comment: why don't you use ngIf?

Comment: using ngIf I can achive that but the thing is both the component will get added to my main.bundle.js and and based on the condition it will render. but I want any one of the component to be picked while I am building this app.

Comment: depending on what the `isAboutusA` variable will change?

Comment: Your HomeComponent won't work if only one component is embedded to your module

Comment: I have to manually change it, so at the time of build any one of the component will go to my main.bundle.js.

Comment: @FabriceJumarie  Yes agreed, that's what I am looking for is there any solution to pick any one from my HomeComponent.